# SQLite Issue when inserting large number of records

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to insert 15530 record in a certain table using SQLite3 shell but i get that error , I searched for the solution SQLITE_MAX_COMPOUND_SELECT which defaults to 500 is the reason , but i don't know how to change it using Shell.

"Error: too many terms in compound SELECT"

http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg861/scaled.php?server=861&filename=sqlite.jpg&res=landing

```
INSERT INTO table_name (my_id, my_name) VALUES
(1, 'Aaliyah'),
(2, 'Alvar Aalto'),
(3, 'Willie Aames'),
...
(15530, 'name');
```

Comment: The SQLITE_MAX_COMPOUND_SELECT setting is not your problem. *You need to reduce the number of terms in your SELECT statement.*  Show us the code you are using.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, well, that’s the solution. But hardcoded limits/array sizes, while preventing a developer from becoming insane or even being more performant than alternatives, are a pity in their own right. It’s not like sqlite has an equivalent to `xargs` to automatically split up bulk inserts into the largest possible (or most commonly efficiently-sized) statements… (or does it?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`INSERT INTO` doesn't work that way.

Try this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
INSERT INTO author (author_id, author_name) VALUES (1, 'Aaliyah')
INSERT INTO author (author_id, author_name) VALUES (2, 'Alvar Aalto')
INSERT INTO author (author_id, author_name) VALUES (3, 'Willie Aames')
...
END TRANSACTION
```

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html

Comment: Thanks, That really made me think differently and rewrite the query to match this

Comment: Um yeah, it *does* work that way, as of version 3.7.11. It's no longer necessary to use this old way of inserting rows each in a separate insert in a transaction.  So why does the new way claim we are doing a compound select, when that is no longer true (the query has "select" nowhere in it!)?

Answer (score 14):

The multiple-value INSERT INTO syntax was [introduced in SQLite 3.7.11](https://www.sqlite.org/changes.html), so the original syntax is fine on recent versions of SQLite.  On older versions, you can use an [alternative syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609637/is-it-possible-to-insert-multiple-rows-at-a-time-in-an-sqlite-database).

However, the limit `SQLITE_MAX_COMPOUND_SELECT` [cannot be raised at runtime](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html), so you need to split your inserts into batches of 500 rows each.  This will be more efficient than inserting one row per query.  E.g.

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO table_name (id, name) VALUES (1, 'foo'), ..., (500, 'bar');
INSERT INTO table_name (id, name) VALUES (501, 'baz'), ..., (1000, 'zzz');
...
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Why does SQLite treat multi-inserts as a select when the syntax does away with that altogether?  This makes no sense, especially in light of the documentation which states: `We think this is a generous allotment since in practice we almost never see the number of terms in a compound select exceed single digits.` but in fact I might have thousands or millions of rows I want to insert in a single statement!

Comment: @Michael, if you’re using sqlite3, you should expect this sort of thing because that’s the point of sqlite3: to be lightweight even if that means excluding certain conveniences found in heavyweight DBs. That makes imposing hardcoded array dimensions on users acceptable in such a library, and even on heavyweight databases you might still want to split up an `INSERT` with a large `VALUES` section into multiple `INSERT`s.