# SQLITE_ERROR 'too many terms in compound SELECT' (1) get this error

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

After inserting 499 data in sqlite i get this error. I want to insert more then 500 data in database. I use Union Select for insert the multiple record in table.For insert more data in databse what i do?

Comment: You should tag this with SQL and SQLite not iOS and objective-C.

Comment: Could you provide some more code an a reproducible example?

Comment: NSString *insert=[NSString stringWithFormat:
 @"Insert  Into  BabyNames(Baby_Name,Language,Meaning,Gender)  Select 'Adi' As Baby_Name, 'Marathi' As Language, 'Winner, Jewel, Ornament, Myth Name Beginning, First Born, Adornment, SuperiorFirst, More Extra' As Meaning, 'B' As Gender Union All Select 'Aja', 'Marathi', 'Fire, Unborn, Purity, Path of Light', 'B'  ........ 'G'"];  i use this

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQLite Issue when inserting large number of records](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10083719/sqlite-issue-when-inserting-large-number-of-records)

Comment: ok thanks will try out